# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'DateTime') even I check there is a data in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm just getting learning React a few weeks ago. So, If I ask a pretty general question, I am sorry. But, It would be really appreciated if you help me out!

- Issue
  :  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'DateTime')
- What I try to solve it
  : Firstly, I tried to solve it generally. I mean I add the condition to progress my code and re-render. Also, I check the data exist or not.
- Code

```
  const changeWeekendDateColor = () => {
    let eventArray = [];
    let weekendArray = [];
    if (weekendData && weekendData.event && weekendData.schedule) {
      let status = false;
      const dataEventLength = weekendData.event.length;
      const dataWeekendLength = weekendData.schedule.length;

      for (let i = 0; i <= dataEventLength; i++) {
        eventArray.push(weekendData.event[i].DateTime.split("T")[0]);
      }

      for (let i = 0; i <= dataWeekendLength; i++) {
        weekendArray.push(weekendData.schedule[i].split(" ")[0]);
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i <= eventArray.length; i++) {
      if (weekendArray.includes(eventArray[i])) return (status = false);
    }

    return status;
  };
  console.log(changeWeekendDateColor(weekendData));
```

WeekendData is this one

[image]

- What I expect
  : I add if statement

```
if (weekendData && weekendData.event && weekendData.schedule)
```

So, I think this should be work because if there is no data, it shouldn't do the next line. I am not sure why my code couldn't approach the weekendData.event.DateTime...

[image]

Comment: The error message is clear, `weekendData.event[i]` is `undefined`.

Comment: @slideshowp2 Can I ask why it is undefined..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` loop can't read undefiened property. `dataWeekendLength` has 7 length but `weekendData.event` only have 1 length from the array.

See `WeekendData.schedule.length`

```
...
schedule: Array(7)
```

And this is `for` loop in the code,

```
      for (let i = 0; i <= dataEventLength; i++) {
        eventArray.push(weekendData.event[i].DateTime.split("T")[0]);
      }
```

The `for` loops 7 times for the `dataEventLength`,

It's `weekendData.event`,

```
...
event: Array(1)
```

If the `for` loop goes on `i = 1` then it will be `weekendData.event[1]`.

But there is no `weekendData.event[1]` but only `weekendData.event[0]`.

The code would work but the array only has one.

Comment: Oh my gosh... I am so stupid. I am struggling with this issue whole day. I changed the condition <= to < and it works as well. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: @JiwanJeon94 Glad your question is solved :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment again! Have a good one :)